# xLookup with two variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

Thanks in advance for your help here. Scenario: I have customers that purchase "credits" in agreed multiples of x, and I need to report when these packs have been depleted.

I'm mining the data from my database, and my data is structured like this:

**Sheet 1:**

| Customer ID | Credit pack | Date purchased | Cumulative Credit Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-02-01 | 20 |
| ABC | 20 | 2023-03-01 | 40 |
| DEF | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 |
| DEF | 5 | 2023-02-01 | 15 |

**Sheet 2**

| Customer ID | Cumulative credits used | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| ABC | 2 | 2023-01-02 |
| ABC | 8 | 2023-01-03 |
| ABC | 30 | 2023-01-15 |

What I'm looking to achieve is finding the date at which the cumulative credit spend exceeded the culumulative credit balance, enabling me to show the date the credit pack would have expired - sheet looking like this:

**Desired result:**

| Customer ID | Credit pack | Date purchased | Cumulative Credit Balance | Date of expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 | 2023-01-15 |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-02-01 | 20 | 2023-01-15 |
| ABC | 20 | 2023-03-01 | 40 |  |
| DEF | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 |  |
| DEF | 5 | 2023-02-01 | 15 |  |

When working with only one customer's dataset, I was able to get the results I wanted by concatenating the customer ID and the cumulative credit balance values, then using an xlookup formula:

**Sheet 1:**

| Customer ID | Credit pack | Date purchased | Cumulative Credit Balance | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 | ABC10 |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-02-01 | 20 | ABC20 |
| ABC | 20 | 2023-03-01 | 40 | ABC40 |
| DEF | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 10 | DEF10 |
| DEF | 5 | 2023-02-01 | 15 | DEF15 |

**Sheet 2**

| Key | Customer ID | Cumulative credits used | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | ABC | 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| ABC2 | ABC | 2 | 2023-01-02 |
| ABC8 | ABC | 8 | 2023-01-03 |
| ABC30 | ABC | 30 | 2023-01-15 |

`=XLOOKUP(sheet1Key,sheet2key,Date,,1,2)`

My issue is when I have additional customers - undoubtedly because my match mode of "1" is struggling.

Can anyone help?

(Edit - fixing table formatting that's annoyingly fine in preview!)

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Down Versions

#### Retrieve Expiry Date (or a different column)

```
=IFERROR(
     XLOOKUP(
         SUM(FILTER(B:B,(A:A=A2)*(C:C<=C2))),
         FILTER(I:I,F:F=A2), FILTER(H:H,F:F=A2),"",1),
     "")
```

[image]

#### Calculate values for Cumul_Used (helper column)

```
=SUM(FILTER(G:G,(F:F=F2)*(H:H<=H2)))
```

[image]

## LAMBDA (Single Formula) Versions

#### Retrieve Expiry Date (or a different column)

```
=LET( _arr, FILTER(A:C, (ROW(A:C)<>1)*(A:A<>"")),
      _id, INDEX(_arr,,1), _date, INDEX(_arr,,3),
      MAP(_id, _date, LAMBDA(id,dt, IFERROR(
         XLOOKUP(
            SUM(FILTER(B:B,(A:A=id)*(C:C<=dt))),
            FILTER(I:I,F:F=id), FILTER(H:H,F:F=id),"",1),""))))
```

[image]

#### Calculate values for Cumul_Used (helper column)

```
=LET( _arr, FILTER(F:H,(ROW(F:F)<>1)*(F:F<>"")),
           _id, INDEX(_arr,,1), _dt, INDEX(_arr,,3),
           MAP(_id, _dt, LAMBDA(id,dt,
                SUM(FILTER(G:G,(F:F=id)*(H:H<=dt))))))
```

[image]